# Python script to clean out old files from a repository

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, file-system

I wrote the script below as my first python program that will be running in a production environment. Essentially this program looks at a source location and moves all the files to a destination location if the file is older than 14 days old and does not exists in the destination. I had a user on stack overflow suggest some variable name changes and I am in the process of doing that. I would love if someone could review this code and let me know if anyone sees any potential bugs or errors that I might run into.

```
import os 
import shutil
import time
import errno
import time
import sys
import logging
import logging.config



source = r'C:\Users\Desktop\BetaSource'
dest = r'C:\Users\Desktop\BetaDest'
#Gets the current time from the time module
now = time.time()
#Timer of when to purge files
cutoff = now - (14 * 86400)
source_list = []
all_sources = []
all_dest_dirty = []
logging.basicConfig(level = logging.INFO, filename = time.strftime("main-%Y-%m-%d.log"))

def main():
    dest_files()
    purge_files()
#I used the dess_files function to get all of the destination files
def dest_files():
    for dest_root, dest_subdirs, dest_files in os.walk(dest):
        for f in dest_files:
            global All_dest_dirty
            all_dest_dirty.append(f)    

def purge_files():
    logging.info('invoke purge_files method')
    #I removed all duplicates from dest because cleaning up duplicates in dest is out of the scope
    all_dest_clean = list(dict.fromkeys(all_dest_dirty))
    #os.walk used to get all files in the source location 
    for source_root, source_subdirs, source_files in os.walk(source):
        #looped through every file in source_files
        for f in source_files:
            #appending all_sources to get the application name from the file path
            all_sources.append(os.path.abspath(f).split('\\')[-1]) 
            #looping through each element of all_source
            for i in all_sources:
                #logical check to see if file in the source folder exists in the destination folder
                if i not in all_dest_clean:
                    #src is used to get the path of the source file this will be needed to move the file in shutil.move
                    src =  os.path.abspath(os.path.join(source_root, i))
                    #the two variables used below are to get the creation time of the files
                    t = os.stat(src)
                    c = t.st_ctime
                    #logical check to see if the file is older than the cutoff
                    if c<cutoff:
                        logging.info(f'File has been succesfully moved: {i}')
                        print(f'File has been succesfully moved: {i}')
                        shutil.move(src,dest)
                        #removing the allready checked source files for the list this is also used in other spots within the loop
                        all_sources.remove(i)
                    else:
                        logging.info(f'File is not older than 14 days: {i}')
                        print(f'File is not older than 14 days: {i}')
                        all_sources.remove(i)
                else:
                    all_sources.remove(i)
                    logging.info(f'File: {i} allready exists in the destination')
                    print(f'File: {i} allready exists in the destination')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a brain dump of some things about your code that I hope you find useful.

## Automated tools

Automated tools can help you maintain your code more easily.

The first ones I install whenever I start a new Python project, are:

- [black](https://github.com/python/black) — The uncompromising Python code formatter
- [isort](https://github.com/timothycrosley/isort) — A Python utility to sort imports
- [flake8](https://github.com/pycqa/flake8) — A tool to enforce PEP 8 compliance (among other things)

I ran them on your code with the following options:

- `pipenv run black clean_old_files.py`
- `pipenv run flake8 --max-line-length 88 clean_old_files.py`
- `pipenv run isort clean_old_files.py -m=3 -tc -l=88`

(An aside, I'm using [Pipenv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv) to manage my [virtual environments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41972261). They're unmissable once you start getting into larger projects with external dependencies, and other contributors.)

## Noisy comments

You have several comments that explain *what* the code does, rather than *why*.

For instance this:

```py
# Gets the current time from the time module
now = time.time()
# Timer of when to purge files
cutoff = now - (14 * 86400)
```

which could be rewritten as:

```py
# Timer of when to purge files
cutoff = time.time() - (14 * 86400)
```

which removes one "what" comment, and inlines a temporary variable.

My advice would be to go over all the comments in your script, and see which are "what" comments, and which are "why" comments.

## Code structure

A minor thing to start off, I'd move the `main` function to the bottom of the script, right before `if __name__ == "__main__"`, which, conceptually makes most sense to me.

You are mutating global variables from functions, which makes it harder to follow your program structure as-is.

On a related note, you also have `global All_dest_dirty`, which is a typo.

## Globals

Instead of, for instance:

```py
all_dest_dirty = []

def dest_files():
    for dest_root, dest_subdirs, dest_files in os.walk(dest):
        for f in dest_files:
            global all_dest_dirty
            all_dest_dirty.append(f)
```

prefer:

```py
def dest_files():
    dirty_files = []
    for dest_root, dest_subdirs, dest_files in os.walk(dest):
        for f in dest_files:
            dirty_files.append(f)

    return dirty_files

all_dest_dirty = dest_files()
```

## Closing remarks

Correct me if I'm wrong, but from

```py
all_dest_clean = list(dict.fromkeys(all_dest_dirty))
```

I think that you're trying to remove duplicates from a list?

You can write that as

```py
all_dest_clean = set(all_dest_dirty)
```

which uses the [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set) data type, which prevents any duplicates. Plus, it's less typing, and also clearer. :-)

---

I hope you found my mini review helpful. You're doing great for a [beginner](/questions/tagged/beginner)! Keep it up. Also, let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: That was a great answer! I love your feedback. I’ll definitely go through and create those functions to return values rather than manipulating global variables. Also id I turned all_dest_clean into a set would I still be able to check if I is not in all_dest_clean? Im not super familiar what the difference between using a list compared to a set.

Comment: @TheMuellTrain Thank you! Re: `would I still be able to check if I is not in all_dest_clean` Yup! That's still possible.

Comment: I have modified the `dest_files()` function to `return dirty_files`. My question now is what is the best practice for defining `all_dest_dirty = dest_files()` I can not define it at the top of my program with the rest of the variables. Is it common to just define this right after the function?